# How can I parse and compare ISO 8601 durations in Python?

Tags: python, iso8601

I'm looking for a library in Python (v2) that will allow me to parse and compare ISO 8601 durations that *may* be in different units

Ideally it would work with the standard operators (a < b) but I would be cool with something like a.compare(b) or however.

so something like:

```
duration('P23M') < duration('P2Y') //True
duration('P25M') < duration('P2Y') //False
```

I've installed isodate from PyPi, but it has its own class for periods that include month and years and they don't compare with either themselves or with timedeltas

Comment: Looking at the specification it doesn't look all that hard to parse yourself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Comment: @MarkRansom: Parsing is easy, comparing is hard. Is `P30D` longer or shorter than `P1M`?

Comment: The answer to that, @Gabe, seems to be that a bare duration, not part of a time interval, is not provided for by the standard. A time interval includes an endpoint date (or "other context") that allows you to make that determination.

Comment: Obviously some combinations aren't comparable - months and years are both variable size and depend on which exact dates you're using. No library is going to help you with solving the impossible. I'd parse it then combine the parts that can be combined, so you have only two quantities, months and seconds. Compare the months and only if they are equal compare the seconds.

Comment: @Gabe, thanks this was a problem. The way I eventually "solved" it was by comparing the resulting values if the period was added to a value holding the current UTC time.

This of course means that during February, P30D is longer than P1M, in March it is shorter and in April it is equal. Not ideal, but met my needs well enough.

Comment: If you solved it, please post an answer for those who find this question in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I eventually "solved" it was by comparing the resulting values if the period was added to a value holding the current UTC time. This of course means that during February, P30D is longer than P1M, in March it is shorter and in April it is equal. Not ideal, but met my needs well enough.

Answer (score 9):

here's a bit of a fudge with the durations (one month is 30 days, one year is an average etc):

```
# parse 8601 duration
from re import findall

def iso8601_duration_as_seconds( d ):
    if d[0] != 'P':
        raise ValueError('Not an ISO 8601 Duration string')
    seconds = 0
    # split by the 'T'
    for i, item in enumerate(d.split('T')):
        for number, unit in findall( '(?P<number>\d+)(?P<period>S|M|H|D|W|Y)', item ):
            # print '%s -> %s %s' % (d, number, unit )
            number = int(number)
            this = 0
            if unit == 'Y':
                this = number * 31557600 # 365.25
            elif unit == 'W': 
                this = number * 604800
            elif unit == 'D':
                this = number * 86400
            elif unit == 'H':
                this = number * 3600
            elif unit == 'M':
                # ambiguity ellivated with index i
                if i == 0:
                    this = number * 2678400 # assume 30 days
                    # print "MONTH!"
                else:
                    this = number * 60
            elif unit == 'S':
                this = number
            seconds = seconds + this
    return seconds

for d in [ 'PT10M', 'PT5H', 'P3D', 'PT45S', 'P8W', 'P7Y', 'PT5H10M', 'P2YT3H10M', 'P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S', 'P23M', 'P2Y' ]:
    seconds = iso8601_duration_as_seconds( d )
    print "%s \t= %s" % (d,seconds)
    print


print '%s' % (iso8601_duration_as_seconds('P23M') < iso8601_duration_as_seconds('P2Y') )
# True
print '%s' % (iso8601_duration_as_seconds('P25M') < iso8601_duration_as_seconds('P2Y') )
# False
```

Comment: This really helped me do some parsing. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the comment in the code suggests that it assumes `1M` to be equal to `30D`. However `2678400/60/60/24` is actually `31D`.

Answer (score 1):

Confronted with the same problem, I resorted to regular expressions to parse the durations and compare the resulting number of seconds:

```
def duration(duration_str):
    match = re.match(
        r'P((?P<years>\d+)Y)?((?P<months>\d+)M)?((?P<weeks>\d+)W)?((?P<days>\d+)D)?(T((?P<hours>\d+)H)?((?P<minutes>\d+)M)?((?P<seconds>\d+)S)?)?',
        duration_str
    ).groupdict()
    return int(match['years'] or 0)*365*24*3600 + \
        int(match['months'] or 0)*30*24*3600 + \
        int(match['weeks'] or 0)*7*24*3600 + \
        int(match['days'] or 0)*24*3600 + \
        int(match['hours'] or 0)*3600 + \
        int(match['minutes'] or 0)*60 + \
        int(match['seconds'] or 0)
```

Note that this implicitly assumes that a year is 365 days, a month is 30 days, etc.

Comment: Your regular expression contains syntax errors - there are missing opening brackets around the years/months/weeks/days groups.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I fixed the regular expression.