# Python command parameter indicating time delta

Tags: python, argparse, duration, timedelta

I need to specify a parameter to a python script indicating time back from now. For example `1d` is 1 day from now, `2h` is 2 hours from now, `2d3h` is 2 days, 3 hours from now. Similar to the `journalctl --vacuum-time` format ([reference](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html)).

For example, this script will collect the data between now and 2 days and 3 hours in the past:

```
collect_data_script.py --start=2d3h
```

Is there some standard way to handle this parameter and a package that can process this time format? Or I will have to write it from scratch?

Comment: You can use argparse to parse the arguments but I am pretty sure you will need to create the logic for handling the time yourself.

Comment: might be better to split into separate --days and --hours args

Comment: To port the logic: systemd's `journalctl` uses a dictionary-based parser in [`time-util.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/basic/time-util.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ISO 8601 duration format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) like `2DT3H` for "2 days (time designator) 3 hours" can be parsed using module [`isodate`](https://pypi.org/project/isodate/) from [Gerhard Weiss](http://github.com/gweis/isodate):

> implements ISO 8601 date, time and duration parsing. The implementation follows ISO8601:2004 standard

> `parse_duration`:
> parses an ISO 8601 duration string into a timedelta or Duration object.

Example:

```
import isodate

isodate.parse_duration('p2d3h'.upper())  # prefix with 'p' for period and to uppercase
# will raise ValueError because ISO 8601 time designator 'T' missing

timedelta = isodate.parse_duration('p2dt3h'.upper())  # insert 'T' to work
# datetime.timedelta(2, 10800)
print(timedelta)
# 2 days, 3:00:00
```

#### Similar modules

- [`arrow`](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/): offers a sensible and human-friendly approach to creating, manipulating, formatting and converting dates, times and timestamps.
- [`duration`](https://pypi.org/project/duration/): python time duration conversion module
- [`iso8601`](https://pypi.org/project/iso8601/): Simple module to parse ISO 8601 dates

See also:

- [How can I parse and compare ISO 8601 durations in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296416/how-can-i-parse-and-compare-iso-8601-durations-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

@hc_dev solution will work. However, I used a slightly different one that needed fewer additional modules. Just posting here for reference:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import parser

def process_cmd_time(time_str, bound) -> datetime:
    """
    Convert passed string to the datetime object.
    Will throw ParseError or ValueError if the string is invalid

    Keyword arguments:
    time_str - string representation of the time to set
    bound - flag to force time bound to 24h from now
    """

    time_str = time_str.strip()
    go_back = time_str[0] == '-'

    # Attempt to get the date. Will throw ParseError if invalid
    input_date = parser.parse(time_str)

    # If the time needs to go back, find the delta from the beginning of today,
    # then subtract from now
    if go_back:
        delta_today = input_date - parser.parse("0h0m0s")
        input_date = datetime.now() - delta_today

    if bound:
        delta_time = datetime.now() - input_date
        if delta_time.days > 0:
            input_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24, minutes=0, seconds=0)

    return input_date
```

Comment: Very robust and well documented function  Like the _reduced dependencies/modules_: Can you explain `parser`, [can't find a `parse(str)` function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/parser.html#module-parser) in Python.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The import section gotten deleted. Will update